# How to set the value of dropdown coming from model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am stuck at "how to set value in the dropdown to the value that is set in the model.

I am adding what I have till now and what I have tried.

So, I have a `PaymentFormMV` Model and it has another Model in it which is `PaymentCCMV`

```
public class PaymentFormMV
{
    public PaymentCCMV CreditDetails { get; set; }
    public string ModelPropertyPrefixName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ModelPropertyPrefix.Replace("_", ".");
        }
    }
}
public class PaymentCCMV
{
    [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
    public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }
}
```

**cshtml file takes data from PaymentFormMV**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth", Helpers.PossibleMonths,
        new { id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails_ExpirationMonth", @class = "form-control", style = "width:70px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Helpers.PossibleMonths: displays all the months**

```
public static ICollection<SelectListItem> PossibleMonths
{
    get
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "1 - Jan", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "2 - Feb", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 - Mar", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 - Apr", Value = "4" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 - May", Value = "5" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 - Jun", Value = "6" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 - Jul", Value = "7" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "8 - Aug", Value = "8" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "9 - Sep", Value = "9" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 - Oct", Value = "10" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "11 - Nov", Value = "11" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 - Dec", Value = "12" },
        };
    }
}
```

Points:

I am getting integer value `model.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth = 2` (as per DB)

But I don't know how to set it to the drop down. So when the screen loads I want that value to be tied to the dropdown. Please guide me. SO, if the value is 2 I should get something like `2 - Feb` in the Dropdown UI as mentioned in the Helper Method. I am a beginner so I might not be following the best practice so bear with me on this.

**HTML GENERATED:**

[image]

Comment: One way would be to use HTML.DropDownListFor. You can then provide your model and default values as a SelectList and htmlAttributes if you require.

Comment: thank you so much for the response. Can you elaborate more.

Comment: Change your code to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth, Helpers.PossibleMonths, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:70px;" })`. If the value of `ExpirationMonth` is say `3`, then `"Mar"` will be selected.

Comment: As a side note, your helper can be simplified to `return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank You so much for the guidance.

Comment: Why negative vote! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second @Vivien's response, but I would recommend to use the overload that takes the selected value ([See MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_6)), which you can then set.  To then allow passing in the default, I would also recommend using a static method, and allowing the month to be passed in:

```
public static SelectList PossibleMonths(string defaultValue)
{
        return new SelectList(List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "1 - Jan", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "2 - Feb", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 - Mar", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 - Apr", Value = "4" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 - May", Value = "5" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 - Jun", Value = "6" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 - Jul", Value = "7" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "8 - Aug", Value = "8" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "9 - Sep", Value = "9" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 - Oct", Value = "10" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "11 - Nov", Value = "11" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 - Dec", Value = "12" },
        }, "Value", "Text", defaultValue);
}
```

EDIT: Your dropdown could would then look like

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth", Helpers.PossibleMonths(Model.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth),
                new { id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails_ExpirationMonth", @class = "form-control", style = "width:70px;" })
```

That assumes the CreditDetails object is always not null, otherwise null  checking is a must.

EDIT: I was incorrect, apparently Html.DropDownList doesn't support SelectList, so I reverted back to the original approach with a twist for setting the selected value (note same drop down code above for this to work).

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PossibleMonths(string defaultValue)
{
        if (defaultValue == null)
           defaultValue = "";

        return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "1 - Jan", Value = "1", Selected = (defaultValue == "1") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "2 - Feb", Value = "2", Selected = (defaultValue == "2") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 - Mar", Value = "3", Selected = (defaultValue == "3") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 - Apr", Value = "4", Selected = (defaultValue == "4") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 - May", Value = "5", Selected = (defaultValue == "5") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 - Jun", Value = "6", Selected = (defaultValue == "6") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 - Jul", Value = "7", Selected = (defaultValue == "7") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "8 - Aug", Value = "8", Selected = (defaultValue == "8") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "9 - Sep", Value = "9", Selected = (defaultValue == "9") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 - Oct", Value = "10", Selected = (defaultValue == "10") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "11 - Nov", Value = "11", Selected = (defaultValue == "11") },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 - Dec", Value = "12", Selected = (defaultValue == "12") },
        };
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly guide me how my cshtml file gonna change as per your helper code.

Comment: As far as I have studied I need to pass one more argument (telling dropdown to take a default value and display it) in the `@Html.DropDownList` right?

Comment: Also, when I say default value I mean to say the logged is user's model data. I mean the form needs to be auto filled by the model data. Not a hardcoded default value. Just saying. I am sure you would have figured that out.

Comment: Well no, selected value is not a property on Html.DropDownList.  You either need to set the Selected attribute on the SelectListItem class, or use SelectList and specify the selected value parameter (4th param in the method I have above).  The view passes the value stored in the model as the default (yep, are that we are not hard-coding a "2" value).

Comment: As soon as I put your`possibleMonths` function I start getting error `cannot resolve the symbol Add` in my Helper.cs file

Comment: I get this error in all the lines where you have added the `new SelectListItem`

Comment: Error: cannot convert expression type `SelectList` to return type `Icollection<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Am I missing something

Comment: I think there is some mismatch in return type. Kindly guide me.

Comment: My bad, my original method was wrong and Vivien was right, but turns out Html.DropDownList doesn't support SelectList at all, so I just modified your original approach to set the selected property for the correct entry.  You may be able to use the SelectList class and use the Items property to get the list of SelectListItem collection anyway, so either approach should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: Both the `DropDownList()` and the preferred `DropDownListFor()` ignore the `Selected` value of `SelectListItem` (internally they build a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) and its the value of the property your binding to the the determines what is selected. The only time it is respected is using `DropDownList("NotAProperty", ...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: If you get some time please do frame your suggestion as an answer in SO it wil help fellow developers including me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

The `DropDownList()` (and the preferred `DropDownListFor()` methods work by binding to the value of your property. In your case, you want to bind to the `ExpirationMonth` property, the code in your view should be

```
@Html.DropDownList("CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth", Helpers.PossibleMonths, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:70px;" }
```

or better

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth, Helpers.PossibleMonths, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:70px;" }
```

and if you have set the value of `ExpirationMonth` to say `3` in the GET method and pass the model to the view, then the 3rd option ("Mar") will be selected.

It is not clear what your `ModelPropertyPrefix` and `ModelPropertyPrefixName` properties return, however they are not required, and should not be used when in the view (the `HtmlHelper` methods will always generate the correct `name` attributes necessary for 2-way model binding).

Note also that it is a common misconception to believe that the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` needs to be set when generating the `SelectList`. When binding to a model property, the `DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` methods internally generate their own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `Selected` property based on the value of the property (any attempt to set it yourself is ignored). The only time the `Selected` property is respected is when you use `DropDownList("xxx", ...)` and `xxx` is not a property or the model.

As a side note, your code in the static method could be just

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PossibleMonths()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeForm‌at.GetMonthName(x)
    });
}
```

and your view models should not contain properties which are data models when editing data. `PaymentFormMV` should contain `public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }` (and other properties of `PaymentCCMV` you need), not `public PaymentCCMV CreditDetails { get; set; }`

---

Based on your edit showing the image of the html, your generating a `name` attribute which does not relate to your `PaymentFormMV` model that is being used in the view (it does not have a property named `PaymentInfo`) and therefore your not correctly binding to the model, and the correct option will not be selected.

From the comments in chat, you need to change the view to use `@model MoveInMV` and then the method will be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentInfo.CreditDetails.ExpirationMonth, Helpers.PossibleMonths, ...)
```

to give correct 2-way model binding.

Comment: I will try to remove "selected" stuff from my code. I had put that just to have initial value to be set on the form when the form loads for the first time. I mean if model has CC Month as 2, then when form loads automatically the month drop down should be pointing at 2. But if I understand you clearly, I just need to use the code you have mentioned above and the dropdown will automatically point at 2 (2- Feb).

Comment: I will definitely try it and will get back to you. Also, about the last point that youu told, I thought that if I keep different classes I will have good separation. So all the "credit card" related fields are put in a separate view model "PaymentCCMV" and it is called in the paymentMV. But I think as per you my view model should not have any other view model. Rather it should directly have all the fields in it.

Comment: Actually PaymentCCMV is also a MV in its own. Its not a domain model. Just saying..

Comment: OK, then that's fine (I just assumed it was a data model).

Comment: I am total beginner. Pardon my ignorance. Do you want me to "inspect the dropdown element" and show you the HTML generated inside it as I run the code.

Comment: Or you want me to put breakpoint somewhere in .cshtml file and check for values or something. Please guide me.

Comment: No, just edit the question to include _the html generated by the method is_  `<select name="xxxx" ...>` - the only thing that is important is the `name` attribute - don't need to see the `<option>` elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128219/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: When you had put your suggestion as comments that just bind the dropdown properly and it take care of itself, that time only I had tried your code and it did not work for me and that's why I had told you to put the explanation as an answer. Unfortunately, because of messed up code (of mine) your code won't work, as clearly the binding will not occur as "PaymentInfo.CreditCardDetails.ExpirationMonth" is not present in my View Model.

Comment: However what ever month I select from my dropdown, I am able to capture it in the backend (with the code that I have put in the question). SO that's a curious thing. May be I should debbug the code a little more and see how still I am able to capture the changes of front end dropdown

Comment: Keep the comments to chat :) - I'll continue there

Comment: May be there is some screwed up hack or something which ignores the "PaymentInfo" text and then binds "CreditCardDetails.ExpirationMonth". I am a beginner so I don't know much.

Comment: This is the question you had downvoted and had advised me to put front end generated code.. :)

Comment: @Unbreakable, I up-voted this question - do you want me to now remove the up-vote and down-vote it? (and the question does not even have any down-votes)

Comment: No Sir. Thank you for all your guidance and answers.